# Why doesn't Java dependency on a constant lead to recompilation?

Tags: java, ant

I have a couple of simple classes:

```
// src/Consts.java
public class Consts
{
    public static final int A = 100;
    public static final int B = 101;
}
```

And:

```
// src/Print.java
public class Print
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("A: " + Consts.A + " B: " + Consts.B);
    }
}
```

I have a simple ant build file:

```
<project name="Test" default="compile" basedir=".">
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>

  <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" debug="on" />
  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

I run `ant`, then run `java -cp build Print`, I get the output I expect, `A: 100, B: 101`.  Fine.  Then I edit Consts.java to set A = 200 and B = 201 and re-run `ant`.  It says "Compiling 1 source file", which is Consts.java (confirmed by looking at time-stamps of class files).  Then I re-run `java -cp build Print` and it prints `A: 100, B: 101`.  Which was unexpected, to say the least.

Googling suggests that the values from Consts are substituted at compile-time into the Print source.  Which is fine, but my question then is: **why did ant+javac not recompile Print when Consts changed?**  There is a clear compile-time dependency between the two.

(I just got bit *so* hard by this issue and it seems to me it is surely a bug in one  of the tools.  Or am I missing something?)

Comment: Related: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=75236

Comment: @AndyTurner I think that link mainly says: ant dependency checking aint good. Is that the point here?

Answer (score 4):

Having looked around a bit further after seeing Andy Turner's link, I think ant is just much dumber than I thought it would be.  From the [javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html):

> Note: Apache Ant uses only the names of the source and class files to
>   find the classes that need a rebuild. It will not scan the source and
>   therefore will have no knowledge about nested classes, classes that
>   are named different from the source file, and so on. See the 
>   task for dependency checking based on other than just
>   existence/modification times.

The mentioned [depend task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/depend.html) even says this explicitly:

> The most obvious example of these limitations is that the task can't
>   tell which classes to recompile when a constant primitive data type
>   exported by other classes is changed. For example, a change in the
>   definition of something like
>
> public final class Constants {        public final static boolean DEBUG=false;    }
>
> will not be picked up by other classes.

Which seems to describe my case exactly.  I think the lesson in all this for me is: (a) don't use ant, (b) if you do, always clean before a build.